# Running two versions of GCC at the same time on a system

Tags: gcc, version

I have a Linux system running Fedora 39 equipped with Nvidia GPU-enabled graphic card. The graphic card and all CUDA toolchain with nvcc compiler are all configured correctly. The only problem is that nvcc (version 12.3) supports up to GCC 12 while the GCC version I have installed is 13.2.1. I have cloned GCC repo for version 11.4.0 and build and installed the compiler successfully with a prefix which is "gcc-11.4.0" which is reachable from "/usr/local/bin". I wanted to know whether is there any safe way to add a symlink and use gcc-11.4.0 instead of version 13.2.1 which is installed by Fedora's package manager so "nvcc" will use it when it calls "gcc" and no incompatibility will happen.
Thanks for your help in advance,
Dan

Comment: OK, I am able to specify host compiler for nvcc like:

nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/local/bin/gcc-11.4.0

The problem is that I get link error when the default linker is launched. I won't get any link error if I let nvcc to use an unsupported version of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I upgraded CUDA toolkit to latest version i.e., version 4 and now latest version of gcc is used without problem.